# virtuemart 2 how to modified the product display in particular Category

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

I am working with a joomla and using virtumart 2 for webshop I want to make the products display one in row as i have done in front page by virtue mart functionality but i am not able find any option to doing this in particular category.

Comment: By default there is no option like that for each category,you should customize the code

Comment: Thanks but how could i customize the code i am using vm 2 which are those files

Comment: In VM2 you can see the product listing pages under components/com_virtuemart/views/productlisting/tmpl/default.php you can check this file and put some custom conditions like checking category ..

Comment: as a follow up to Jobin Jose, it is also possible to set a different custom template per category.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to set how many products you want to display in a row:

```
Configuration -> Templates -> Default number of products in a row
```

Hope this helps